# Bash glob, how to OR over strings of non unit length?

Tags: bash, glob

I have in a directory a bunch of files. Each file's basename ends with a two digit number and a letter, such as file_01A.txt, file_03B.txt, file_13A.txt.

In a terminal using bash (I assume, working on a mac osx) I use

`ls *01*[AB]*.txt`

returns all files such as 01A and 01B. This makes sense to me.

`ls *02*[AB]*.txt`

returns similarly all files such as 02A and 02B.

Now I want to return all files 01A, 01B, 02A, 02B. Hence I want something like:

`ls *(01 or 02)*[AB]*.txt`

Attempt 1: I tried with `|` but that throws an error.

Attempt 2: `ls *[01,02]*[AB]*.tex` but that gives the 03 files too, since I assume it is interpreting the 01 and 02 as individual matches.

Attempt 3: `ls *["01","02"]*[AB]*.tex` is the same again.

Comment: Try  `ls *0[12]*[AB]*.tex`

Comment: `ls *02*[AB]*.txt` is going to match on a file named `abc02_A_325.txt`, while `ls *_01[AB].txt` is going to limit the matches to `file_01A.txt`; for the specific question how about `ls *_0[12][AB].txt`

Comment: A "bash regex" is something like `[[ $name =~ (01|02}.*[AB].* ]]`. What your question is about is _glob expressions_, which are a different thing.

Comment: You're more likely using zsh, not bash, on a Mac.

Comment: `[12]` will work the same way `[AB]` does. You can also use commas and `|`s, but not the way you tried. A few examples: (a) `*0[12]*[AB]*` (b) `*0{1,2}*{A,B}*` (c) `*0@(1|2)*@(A|B)*`

Comment: bash globs are not regexp, so such constructions like () are not works.
Try to use find or just try several globs to get all files you want.

```ls *01*[AB]*.txt *02*[AB]*.txt```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to articulate a single wildcard which matches your requirement.

```sh
ls *0[12]*[AB]*.tex
```

In the general case, use multiple wildcards if you can't articulate a single one. Notice that the shell expands them in the order you write them, and if they both match some files, there will be duplicates in the expansion.

```sh
ls *01*[AB]*.tex *02*[AB]*.tex
```

You seem to be confused about what the metacharaters mean. `*` matches any string, `?` matches any character, and `[abc]` matches any one character which is listed between the square brackets. `[!abc]` watches a single character which is not `a`, `b`, or `c`. Bash also supports an extension called brace expansion, where `foo{bar,quux}` is basically an abbreviation of `foobar fooquux`. Your attempt could thus be rearticulated as

```
ls *{01,02}*[AB].tex
```

though the repeated prefix `0` is obviously redundant, and would better be left outside the braces, and then you might as well switch back to straight square brackets.

There is also a separate extended globbing syntax which allows for more elaborate wildcards. See the [reference  manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) for details.